# Firebase conectivity issue - Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Firebase project that already has an iOS app. I have added an android app to the project. It gets stuck on this step:

[image]

I have `uninstalled/reinstalled/clean cache/rebuild/burn emulator, buy another one/I verified that the SHA-1 is correctly for the build variant that I have added to the console/etc.` it still remained stuck. I have also deleted the app from the project and added it again several times.

With another account I have created another Firebase project, then I have created a new android app that I have added (*same steps as above*) to the new Firebase project and it worked (*for the new app with the new project*).

But for the existing Firebase project with the existing android app that I have, no matter what I'ved done it keeps saying "*Checking if the app has communicated with our servers. You may need to uninstall and reinstall your app.*"

In the end I have clicked *Skip this step*

**The problem is that the app it is not linked with the Firebase**, when I look in the console I still see 0 active devices, but I should see 2 devices that I have tested on:

[image]

I have added the exactly versions from here:

[image]

What should I look for, **what can be the possible causes for that app not being connected with Firebase?**

Comment: Any two projects cannot have an app with the same application ID and SHA-1 hash.  The old one has to be deleted, or the new one must be different in some way.

Comment: That's not the problem, i will update the question

Comment: @DougStevenson, well, he questioned at first, the duplicate ID wasn't a thing at first, I answered his first question, didn't solve anything, so we had a teamviewer session and we both checked the code for firebase connectivity like 10 times to see if there were any errors, there were none. And this point we both gave up and I told him to add new question. It has something to do with firebase itself, I don't know if it helps. His app is literally not connecting to firebase even after doing everything.

Comment: If you're expecting the Analytics stats to be updated instantly, that's not how it works.  It takes time to update the console.  If it really isn't updating at all after waiting a day, then contact Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @DougStevenson Nope, it's not stats that's giving problem. Everything else is not getting connected to the app. Not receiving notifications from Firebase, I even checked the code for notifications, everything is correct. I wanted to add bounty, but can't do that for like 2 days.

Comment: Contact Firebase support.

Comment: Make sure that you're using updated SDK versions, your google-services.json file is updated and try running the app using a physical device. Those were the common items I've done to solve that last step.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: yes, i was using the wrong .json file